# 'Magic' ERD generator MySQL, MS SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, erd

I haven't managed to find a specific answer to this question which works for me, but maybe i'm misunderstanding one or two key points.

I am trying to create a data migration policy for a project where 3 systems (2 X MySQL, 1 X MS SQL) are being consolidated into 1 new system (MS SQL).

To help visualize this problem i want to create Entity Relationship Diagrams for each database. I know how to reverse engineer each database to a sql script, and i know that programs like MySQL Workbench and SQL server management studio have tools which allow you to create diagrams.

My question is: Is there any way to create the diagrams automatically? I.e. somehow analyse foreign keys and detect which field(s) in table A link to table B and insert links in the diagram between the correct fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just realised that the databases i am testing with do not have foreign key constraints set up properly. So i guess the answer is yes, there are ways you can create these diagrams automatically but the foreign keys must be configured.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Management Studio comes with a diagramming tool. In the **Object Explorer**, expand your database, then right click on **Database Diagrams**. You can view and create new FK relationships in there.